# How to return only selected fields from a text search using mongodb nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, full-text-search

I am using native mongodb nodejs driver to perform a text search against my mongodb database, I've written a simple code as following, which it works fine with no errors, but it returns all fields, and I tried to figure out how to return only fields that I am interested in, I have tried to find any document  in wiki and manual , but no luck at all.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

```
var dbclient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
dbclient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  var search;
  if (err) {
    callback(err, null);
    return;
  }
  search = {
    text: collection,
    search: "a test"
  };
  return db.command(search, function(err, o) {
    db.close();
    return callback(err, o);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any reason you are using db.command() rather than db.collection().find() ? http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find

Comment: find() doesn't work for full text search as far as I know, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: starting in 2.6 find() will work with text search queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the projection field.

It's documented here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/#specify-which-fields-to-return-in-the-result-set

You could change your search variable to include the project field like this:

```
search = {
    text: collection,
    search: "a test",
    project: {"test": 1}
};
```

Comment: awesomes! really works, damn, I did think about that, but didn't have the courage of giving a try, thanks!

Comment: One more thing add to ranman's answer, the -1 doesn't work, it seems like only support what fields to be returned, not for fields not to be returned

Comment: Ah, good point, I forgot about that. You can only do one or the other -- you can't mix and match unfortunately.